# C++ Destructor Exception

Tags: c++

I am a novice programmer working on some code for school. When the following code is executed, the word BAD is output. I do not understand why the letter C in the destructor is not output when the WriteLettersObj object is terminated.

```
// Lab 1 
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class WriteLetters {
public:
    WriteLetters();
    void writeOneLetter();
    ~WriteLetters();
} WriteLettersObj;

WriteLetters::WriteLetters() {
    cout << "B";
}

void WriteLetters::writeOneLetter() {
    cout << "A";
}

WriteLetters::~WriteLetters() {
    cout << "C" << endl;
}

int main() {
    WriteLettersObj.writeOneLetter();
    cout << "D";
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you remove getch() does it print out BADC?  I ran on Unix through g++ removed getch() and the stdafx/conio.h headers and it prints out BADC.

Comment: I tried it without getch(), it does

Comment: Even with `getch()` also it works, the only thing is his screen goes away before he can see the output. Look at my answer below.

Comment: Are you sure about the result?  `std::cout` does not get destroyed, so `C` should certainly be printed.  (Why are you calling `getch()` at all?  It seems to serve no purpose.)

Comment: @James McNellis - In Visual C++ 2010, the output window gets closed and we should actually set break point at the final `return` statement. Once we continue after this break point, the output window get's closed and destructor call `cout` statement is not seen. I mean to say, the output window is immediately closed though the destructor is actually called. So, OP might be actually thinking destructor isn't called at all. With that in mind, I was quoting my answer. Let me know if I am wrong. @AI T - http://ideone.com/KEbu3

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing iostream with non-ANSI conio.h.

Make this change:

```
// getch();
cin.get();
```

Hey presto, the C appears.  At least on OS X it does.  And Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes. This seems to make sense.

Comment: There are ways to make C++ and C I/O play nice with each other, but in general, don't bother and just use one or the other exclusively.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone, like std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio ?  Will that reach into most plausible implementations of conio?

Comment: I haven't tried it, I just saw it. Does it work well? I figure using that a lot makes I/O act more like it was unbuffered.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is live until you exit the `main()` with `return 0` instruction. Since the `WriteLettersObj` is a global variable, it will be constructed before `main()` starts and destructed after `main()` finishes and not after `getch()`.

To see your output getting printed, put `getch()` in the end of destructor.

Comment: Thank you, I think I get it now. If the object was instantiated in main, you would see it. Since it is instantiated before main, it is destructed after return 0.

Comment: Another reason you'll hear people say that globals should be avoided.

Comment: The iostream object std::cout is instantiated before main, too.  The C++ runtime creates std::cout as part of the initialization that happens before main, and destroys it after main.  If you remember to flush(), you should expect to see your output.  The problem is you are writing to the std::cout object, but then activating a competing library's hook to STDOUT with the conio::getch(), and this messes things up.  conio probably does not know about iostream; my guess is conio is closing STDOUT because it thinks it owns it, so when iostream tries to do the final write and flush, STDOUT is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code **without** getch on linux and Mac and it runs just fine. @iammilind is right that you should move getch in the destructor.

Comment: I was using the getch() as a way to pause the output so that I could see what was there before the window was closed. Interestingly, if I put a getch() in the destructor, you see the C being output. So you are right, it is actually there but the timing of the window closing does not allow you to see it.

Comment: A better idea to keep the window open is to run the program in a 'cmd' window (assuming you are on Windows)